# gcloud not found or permission denied

Tags: gcloud

I have `gcloud auth login` and the user is set in browser console as:

```
Editor
Service Account Admin
Owner
```

And `cloud auth list` shows the user as active.

Now why do I get the following error when calling :

```
gcloud services enable cloudapis.googleapis.com


ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) User [email@mydomain.com] does not have permission to access service [cloudapis.googleapis.com:enable] (or it may not exist): Project '<project-name>' not found or permission denied.
```

## Update

If I do(Suggested by @Yurci) `gcloud services enable cloudapis.googleapis.com --verbosity=debug --log-http`:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.services.enable] with arguments: [--log-http: "true", --verbosity: "debug", SERVICE:1: "[u'cloudapis.googleapis.com']"]
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/cloudapis.googleapis.com:enable?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
Authorization: --- Token Redacted ---
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 42
content-type: application/json
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk x_Tw5K8nnjoRAqULM9PFAC2b gcloud/214.0.0 command/gcloud.services.enable invocation-id/78cec66e69f54740846a1c904be12273 environment/None environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/2.7.15 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 17.7.0)
== headers end ==
== body start ==
{"consumerId": "project:<The project name>"}
== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
cache-control: private
content-length: 149
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 16:13:02 GMT
server: ESF
status: 403
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Project '<The right project>' not found or permission denied.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 1.157 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
DEBUG: (gcloud.services.enable) User [<right email>] does not have permission to access service [cloudapis.googleapis.com:enable] (or it may not exist): Project '<The right project>' not found or permission denied.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 839, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 770, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/services/enable.py", line 161, in Run
    operation = enable_api.EnableServiceApiCall(project, service_name)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/enable_api.py", line 63, in EnableServiceApiCall
    exceptions.EnableServicePermissionDeniedException)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/exceptions.py", line 55, in ReraiseError
    core_exceptions.reraise(klass(api_lib_exceptions.HttpException(err)))
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/exceptions.py", line 139, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/enable_api.py", line 58, in EnableServiceApiCall
    return client.services.Enable(request)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/servicemanagement/v1/servicemanagement_v1_client.py", line 829, in Enable
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "<path>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
EnableServicePermissionDeniedException: User [<right email>] does not have permission to access service [cloudapis.googleapis.com:enable] (or it may not exist): Project '<The right project>' not found or permission denied.
ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) User [<right email>] does not have permission to access service [cloudapis.googleapis.com:enable] (or it may not exist): Project '<The right project>' not found or permission denied.
```

Comment: You need at least [Service Usage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control#roles) role to enable or disable services. If you already have Project Editor and Owner roles you should also be able to enable/disable services. Can you double check if the account has Project Editor/Owner role or can you try to add Service Usage Admin role to the account?

Comment: Thanks, I can verify that both Project Editor/Owner and now also Service Usage Admin is added. I still get the the same error.

Comment: Can you run the command with the following flags 
`gcloud services enable cloudapis.googleapis.com --verbosity=debug --log-http`  
This way you will receive more details about the issue. You can take a look at the flags definition [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/). If possible post the output here after sanitizing your private data.

Comment: Thanks, just updated with the debug message. Removed my information and added <some text>

Comment: In this case can you try the [Service Management API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/servicemanagement/servicemanagement/v1/servicemanagement.services.enable?serviceName=cloudapis.googleapis.com&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522consumerId%2522%253A+%2522project%253A%253CPROJECT_ID%253E%2522%250A%257D&) directly? I've added the serviceName, you need to add your project id and authenticate with the e-mail address you have been trying.

Comment: I got it working - thanks